# Webview Link Controls for Cocoa App

Tags: javascript, html, macos, cocoa, webview

Is there a way to control links in webview?  The scenario is dealing with external protocol links such as mailto://, irc://, target=_blank, and anything else that may provoke a launch of a new window or app.  Maybe it would pop up an nsrunalert saying that 'External links has been disabled'.  Would this be something that javascript would handle or some functions within webview itself?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to set yourself up as a WebResourceLoadDelegate and implement webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003836 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Implement what buts of the WebPolicyDelegate you need. All navigation goes through there